# React + AWS Cognito: Prevent login to Admin dashboard by low-level user

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, roles

My React-AWS application is structured to have 2 user types: managers and their employees. Managers can see all their employees' information and employees can only see their own. Managers are the only users that should be able to sign in to the admin **web** dashboard (where they can create/edit employee data). I don't want employees to be able to read any employee's information other than their own records in Dynamo, let alone sign into the dashboard at all. An answer to a similar question linked below basically said that this is client-side authorization logic. Because I am developing with React, I prefer to keep as much authentication logic invisible in the back-end as possible. What do y'all think?

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=794143&#794143

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that person told you implement the logic on front end when you can easily do this using cognito and IAM policies. First of all you only need a single user pool. You can create 3 groups within this pool and create and attach required roles to these groups depending on what rights you want them to have. Then create a federated identity pool and select the cognito user pool you just created as identity provider and select "choose role from token" from the dropdown under it.

Now all you need to do in front end is provide login screen and call the react sdk for aws cognito.

Comment: Interesting @Ninad Gaikwad. The question remains: how can I prevent a low-level user from logging in? The SDK doesn't require you to specify group id. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html
This example is the closest to documentation I could find.

Comment: if you want to completely prevent a normal user from accessing some front end view, you can find their group from the idtoken and then stop non admins from accessing the dashboard.

Comment: that would be a front-end check right? Or if not, how is that check done on the back-end?

Comment: Yes, if you intend to stop user accessing pages you created in front end you'll have to put a check in front end. You should however still attach roles that will prevent non admin users from accessing any information from back end that you don't want them to have access to.